# HTML/CSS background issue

Tags: html, css

```css
body
{
background:url("Images/Wheat.jpg");
}
p 
{
    font-family: "Sans-serif";
    font-size: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #DEB887;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    }

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #E2A76F;
}
h2

{color:#996633;
font-family:Arial;
text-align: center; 
font-size: 200%;
}

h3
{
font-family:Sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
text-align:left;
font-size: 130%;
}
h4
{
color:#996633;
font-family:Arial;
font-style: italic;
text-align:left;
font-size: 200%%;
}
h5
{
color:#996633;
font-family:Arial;
font-style: italic;
text-align:left;
font-size: 200%%;
}
h6
{
font-family:Sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
text-align:left;
font-size: 130%;
}

@media print {
    p {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: Black;
    }
}
```

CSS code, path of image is correct. Stopped working when I changed the CSS for links. I have tried to use a differet path but the image still wont work. I'm a newbie to this (regretting it!). I don't think it's a problem with the HTML5, I'm just wracking my brain now trying to work out what the hell is going wrong!

Comment: please paste your code not include an image

Comment: have you checked the relative path to the file?

Comment: Best guess:  Your background image isn't where your link says it is.  Alternate guess: You have case-sensitive file names and the case in the CSS doesn't match that of the file or directory.

Comment: I've double checked the path and it's working fine, I'm also having issues with posting the code on this site, please bear with me as soon as it will allow or I work out the spacing issue I will.

Comment: `E:\Websitetwo\Menu.css` I dont see a `CSS\*` folder

Comment: @salniro the `.css` is most likely in the Websitetwo folder.

Comment: Like I say It was working perfectly fine till I changed the CSS code for the links than now it just wont load.

Comment: @KeeleyLouiseWainman In your browser open the developer tools, F12 for Chrome/FireFox/Internet Explorer, and refresh your page. If the page cannot find your image you'll get a `404 resource cannot be found` error.

Comment: I'm not getting that error

Comment: Any errors at all?
Also in your h4 and h5 CSS you're `font-size:` is set to 200%%. Remove one of the `%`. I doubt it'll fix it, but hey it's one less error.
Also can we get your HTML to look at?

Comment: Thankyou, I found the issue.. You guys are amazing!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
background:url("Images/Wheat.jpg");
```

this is correct,

but please check if the capital letters are actually in the map name and in the name of your file,

if this is the case check the following:

1. if you have a styles folder where you place your .css files, check if your 'Images' folder is within the styles folder. If this is the case good, if not & your 'Images' folder is in your main directory use the following:

   background:url("../Images/Wheat.jpg");

what `../` does is it goes back 1 map and then it will go into the Images folder and select your image

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure the path to the image IS correct, including capital letters, and the path. At the moment, the folder where this CSS file is in, is assuming there's a folder inside it called 'Images', which your image 'Wheat.jpg' is inside that. Is this correct?

There's a couple of errors in your CSS styling, you had an extra % symbol. I've also tidied up your CSS code so it's easier to read.

Also the Top, Left, Bottom and Right values in your link and visited, you don't need those as these are only valid for absolute and relative positioning items, where as yours are blocks.

```
body {
    background:url("Images/Wheat.jpg");
}

p {
    font-family: "Sans-serif";
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #DEB887;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #E2A76F;
}

h2 {
    color:#996633;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 200%;
}

h3 {
    font-family:Sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 130%;
}

h4 {
    color:#996633;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 200%;
}

h5 {
    color:#996633;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 200%;
}

h6 {
    font-family:Sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 130%;
}
```